# live coverage setup .. need advice

Tags: wordpress, scaling

i plan to live blog from a show and expect atleast 5-10K users on the live blog

I have setup 2 servers

1. live.domain.com with wordpress running apache and nginx proxy to serve images
   (1024MB RAM linode)
2. livedata.domain.com with meteor server as advised by the liveblogging plugin

(256 MB RAM rackspace cloudserver)

need advice about how to scale this setup for the handling upto 10K concurrent users

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what you mean by "live blog". My understanding of a blog is that someone writes it, others read it and possibly contribute a comment. How does yours differ from that?

Comment: live blog is something like instant new posts on a blog or a post which is updated in real time. users get updates instantly and dont have to reload the pages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 0):

Scaling estimates need much more information than you're giving. Also, cloud-servers make any estimates fuzzy. The specific version of MySQL you're running, as well as how it is configured, can have impacts to how far you can go. The specific version of wordpress, and any plugins beyond liveblog in use on your event page, also impact how far you can go.

My gut says your environment is not beefy enough for this. But that's just my gut feel, based on what little information I have and an exceedingly loose understanding of how WP scales.

Comment: thanks sysadmin .. i too think the env is not powerful enough.. will load test on a physical server to get an idea of the processes